# Handling an exception as a method argument

Tags: java, design-patterns, exception

I am looking for a design pattern to handle `Exception` instances received as method arguments.

To put some context into the question, I am using GWT and have various asynchronous handlers that usually come in a form similar to:

```
public interface AsyncCallback<T> {

  void onFailure(Throwable caught);

  void onSuccess(T result);

}
```

So, the `onFailure` method receives a `Throwable` instance that I need to handle.

Now, I have a number of exceptions I can receive in this method, for example

- `ConstraintViolationException`
- `TimeoutException`
- `NoSuchElementException`

In my handling code I could of course write the following:

```
void handleException(final Exception e) {
    if(e instanceof TimeoutException) {
        handleTimeout();
    } else if (e instanceof NoSuchElementException) {
        handleInvalidElement();
    } else {
        stopAndCatchFire();
    }
}
```

But to my eye, that looks very ugly. The large `if..else if` chain combined with heavy usage of `instanceof` seems like something that should be avoided.

I thought that maybe I could use the `try...catch` construct to handle the `Exception` using something like the following:

```
void handleException(final Exception e) {
    try {
        throw e;
    } catch (TimeoutException te) {
        handleTimeout();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException nsee) {
        handleInvalidElement();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        stopAndCatchFire();
    }
}
```

But this seems like an abuse somehow. Do you see any downsides to the second approach or another approach I could go with to avoid the first case?

Comment: the second is definitely the worse anti-pattern. It's also very unperformant.

Comment: The second would have fairly poor performance (though not as expensive as the first throw, since the majority of the cost is in building the exception), and kind of ugly conceptually.  You might consider getting the exception name and doing a `switch` on that (though it wouldn't handle subclasses).

Comment: @djechlin interesting. Why do you reckon it's a worse anti-pattern? Performance in the second case would undoubtedly be poorer.

Comment: @OliverWatkins - Only if the final `catch` isn't for Exception (or whatever the parameter type is).

Comment: @HotLicks switch on name doesn't work exactly because it doesn't handle subclasses. Having to add subclasses would violate OCP.

Comment: (How many cases are you realistically expecting?  Up to about 5 I'd go with the `if` statements and not worry about those dreaded "anti-patterns".  (The folks who coin terms like "anti-pattern" usually don't know how to program anyway.))

Comment: have you looked the | in Java8 for catching exceptions? You can do something like catch(ExceptionA | ExceptionB e). Not sure if it will help but maybe there is a solution there.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - Only if you're OCD.

Comment: @HotLicks you are probably right. I doubt there will be more that 5 cases: there are only so many ways a request can go wrong (and can be distinguished). Was just hoping someone knew some Better Way (TM).

Comment: Is there any way you could elegantly include an identifier with the throwable? Like handleException(Exception e, int id) ? This way a switch would be good.

Comment: (And the correct operation is "[haltAndCatchFire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire)" (abbreviated "HCF"), not "stopAndCatchFire".)

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja - I would guess that the intended use is to have `catch (Exception ex)` clauses elsewhere and have them route to this routine.  So no classification of the of the exception would have been done.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja indeed. The exceptions come form the _server side_ or from some communication error with the server. So they are thrown, serialized, and received on the client. I have _some_ control over the types thrown and the code used to throw them but there are some exceptions thrown up by the framework that I do not control.

Comment: @HotLicks but even then it would be possible to include an identifier with the routine: `catch (TimeoutException ex) { onFailure(ex, Id.TimeoutException); }` etc

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ah, I see. I think you are stuck with ugliness :(

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja - Not if you `catch (Exception ex)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you not have a dictionary of exceptionHandlers keyed by the type of exception they handle, then when you get a exception you look in the dictionary for the handler for the exception type. If there is one, then pass the exception to the handler, if there isn't then use the default handler.

So your handler becomes something like this:

```
void handleException(final Exception e) {
    if (handlers.containsKey(e.getType())
    {
        handlers[e.getType()].handle(e);
    }
    else
    {
         defaultHandler.handle(e);
    }
}
```

My Java is a bit rusty, so the example is c-sharpy but should be simple enough to translate (though I remembered not to capitalise the first letter of everything :))

This approach should have the advantage that you can add new handlers simply.

It will however suffer if you have the same handler for sub types, as you will have to register each subtype explicitly.

To get around this issue simply make each handler responsible for making the decision about whether it can handle an exception:

```
public interface ExceptionHandler
{
     bool canHandle(Exception e);
     void handle(Exception e)
}
```

then just put the handlers in a list an iterate asking each one if it can handle the current exception and when you find one that can, get it to handle it.

Comment: Now that is a very clever idea! I will investigate and get back to you.

Comment: Just bare in mind that using this approach you would need a handler for each sub-type of a particular exception.  Which may or may not be a problem.

Comment: @StuPointerException yes, I am thinking of using the pattern Spring uses for its handlers, where each handler has a `canHandle` method. This _should_ get me around the subclass problem.

Comment: @StuPointerException, yeah thats true although I was in the process of adding an option for dealing with that, if indeed it is an issue

Comment: @SamHolder +1 nice solution using the ExceptionHandler interface.

Answer (score 1):

> But to my eye, that looks very ugly. The large if..else if chain combined with heavy usage of instanceof seems like something that should be avoided.

I don't agree.  I think this snippet of code is using both language constructs exactly how they were intended.  If the code becomes unmanageable (too many clauses) then you should question the approach to error handling generally, rather than the specifics of this method.  At that stage you might want to consider AOP.

The second approach on the other hand is horrible ;)

Comment: Point taken. AOP is not an option I don't think because it's GWT code. But GWT has it's own ways and means in that regard. They're just **really** grim.

Comment: I don't agree, the onFailure method should be simple. By adding logic in the onFailure method your spreading logic that actually belongs to the service that's being called to client-logic, making it harder to maintain.

Comment: Personally I would find it easier to maintain since you're encapsulating error handling functionality into a single place.  Obviously there is the danger that it becomes a God Object but I think that's just something to keep an eye on!

Answer (score 1):

You can make it more elegant just by handling the if statements inside the exceptions inside the function.

```
void handleException(Exception e){
    handleOne(e)
    handleTwo(e)
    ...
}
```

It looks prettier. Of course, every function is always called, but its first line is just an if statement. There are variations - e.g. make your handle functions guava function objects, put them in a list, and iterate through them until you get the first one that returns "true". Something like:

```
public class handlerOne implements Function<Exception, Boolean> {

    Boolean apply(Exception input) {        
        return handlerOne();
    }
}
```

Then your handle function can be something like:

```
void handleException(Exception e){
    list<Function<Exception, Boolean> list = Object.getHandlers(); //store your handlers somewhere
    for(Function<Exception, Boolean> f : list){
        if(f.apply(e)){
            break
        }
    }
}
```

That way you insure only one handler which works is called, and you can control the order by changing the order of the list, since the list iterator will return them in order.

Answer (score 0):

Control flow on exceptions should be avoided, and should certainly not be in the onFailure. the onFailure method should be as simple as possible.

Modify whatever code is run asynchronously to handle the exception cases there. The ElementNotFound-exception could be handled by just checking if an element exists prior to doing anything. Timeout-exception could be handled by surrounding the code that can timeout (calling a webservice or something)?) by a try .. catch block.
Then extend the result-type T to contain extra information that a timeout occurred or an element is not found - if needed.

Comment: I agree with your first statement entirely, although I don't think this is an example control flow based on exceptions, rather a coordinated exception handler - which is often a good thing.